# Count Down timer counts down only 1 second than stops in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to make a server side count down timer only in seconds:

Here is my Button where starts the Timer:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    int counter = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
        Timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
        Label1.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Than call Timer control:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter = 150;
            
    counter--;
            
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
    
    Label1.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is that when I click on Button it stops at first second count down

I also want to ask if I can use StopWatch class as countDown  timer cause it is more accurate in counting in seconds if you can please give me an example in it...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, how did you wind up with a page called _Default? I've been browsing the web for 20 years now - I've never seen a page start with a underscore.

Next, why do you have a trigger defined for the update panel? You don't need one, nor do you want one. So, remove that.

So, let's create a new page.

Let's call it CountDownTest.aspx.

OK, so we first drag in a script manager (they are always required for update panels).

Then we can drop in our markup.

Let's have "minutes" and "seconds" for the count down. And then a start button, and a stop button.

And let's use a "time span" as you also asked about.

So, we have this so far:

Assuming we have Bootstrap installed, let's format out our boxes a bit.

So we have this markup:

```
    <style>
        .mybox {border:4px solid;
               width:38px;
               height:36px;
               text-align:center;
               font-size:larger
        }
    </style>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" 
            Enabled="False" 
            Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>


        <div style="float:left;text-align:center">
            <font size="4">Minutes</font>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMinutes" runat="server" Text="0"
                CssClass="mybox">
            </asp:TextBox>

            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server"
                Text="Start"
                CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="cmdStart_Click" />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;text-align:center;margin-left:25px">
            <font size="4">Seconds</font>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSeconds" runat="server" Text="10"
                CssClass="mybox">
            </asp:TextBox>

            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="cmdStop" runat="server"
                Text="Stop" Enabled="false"
                CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClick="cmdStop_Click" />

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Note HOW we set the timer control as disabled (in the markup is fine).

And note how the stop button also disabled.

Our code behind then needs a start button event, stop button event, and the timer tick event.

We have this code:

```
public partial class CountDownTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void cmdStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdStart.Enabled = false; // disable the start button
        cmdStop.Enabled = true;   // enable the stop button

        TimeSpan MyTime = new TimeSpan(0, 
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtMinutes.Text), 
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtSeconds.Text));

        ViewState["MyTime"] = MyTime;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;   // start the clock!!!

    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan MyTime = (TimeSpan)ViewState["MyTime"];
        TimeSpan OneSec = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

        MyTime = MyTime.Subtract(OneSec);
        ViewState["MyTime"] = MyTime;

        txtMinutes.Text = MyTime.Minutes.ToString();
        txtSeconds.Text = MyTime.Seconds.ToString();

        if (MyTime.TotalSeconds <= 0)
        {
            // no time left
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            cmdStart.Enabled = true;
            cmdStop.Enabled = false;
        }

    }

    protected void cmdStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        cmdStart.Enabled = true;    
        cmdStop.Enabled = false;    
    }
}
```

And now the effect is this:

[image]